# which is correct php.ini file to use in apache2?

Tags: apache2, php, lamp

Running 16.04, Lamp stack setup and running OK.
Have several versions of php shown in /etc:

/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini, 
/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini, 
and /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

Similar situation exists for /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini and so on.
In a terminal window, the output of

```
php -i | grep 'php.ini'
```

is

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.2/cli
```

Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
So I gather that running php at the command line is using php version 7.2

My info.php file (http://localhost/info.php shows that apache2 is using php version 7.0:

> PHP Version 7.0.27-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
>   How do I get apache2 to use php versioin 7.2?

Comment: At times different php.ini files are used for apache and the command line as you have observed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check your apache config](https://serverfault.com/questions/428800/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use#469849) to see what modules apache is loading. You should look for a line like this:

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/libphp7.so
```

And change it to the php module you want to use. Something more like this:

```
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/libphp72.so
```

Of course this assumes that you have the php module inside apache's modules directory.

You can also [specify](https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-specify-a-custom-php.ini-for-a-website-apache2-with-mod_php) a certain `php.ini` for apache to use.

Comment: Did it!  I ran sudo a2dismod php7.0 and got this:  $ sudo a2dismod php7.0
Module php7.0 disabled.
To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
  systemctl restart apache2  then restarted apache2, re-created phpinfo.php, and now I'm using php7.2!  Victory is sweet.  Thanks so much for the help, could not have done it otherwise.

Comment: You were right, in file /etc/apache2/mods-available/php7.2.load is the line LoadModule php7_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.2.so

Answer (score 2):

You can enable a different `mod_php` for apache2. Try

`$ a2enmod php7.2`

This should disable previous versions and create `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.2.conf` with proper `php.ini` location.

If you don't have this mod, run `$ apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.2`.

Keep in mind that you need to restart apache2 to see changes in loaded modules.

Comment: Thanks, I did run the code above, and this was the output:  (Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libapache2-mod-php7.2 is already the newest version (7.2.2-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
libapache2-mod-php7.2 set to manually installed. )  Not sure of how to "manually install"

Comment: @HenryHall That just means it's already installed and set to not be uninstalled when its parent package is removed. What did `a2enmod php7.2` output?

Comment: If one uses a2enmod php7.2 is it necessary to also use a2dismod php7.0?  In other words, should the existing php7.0 be disabled if php7.2 is to be enabled?

Comment: Just saw your comment.  I've lost the output of the original a2enmod, when I run it now I get $ a2enmod php7.2
Considering dependency mpm_prefork for php7.2:
Considering conflict mpm_event for mpm_prefork:
Considering conflict mpm_worker for mpm_prefork:
Module mpm_prefork already enabled
Considering conflict php5 for php7.2:
Module php7.2 already enabled

Comment: @HenryHall If you run `a2dismod` without any arguments you will see a list of enabled modules. If there are both phps, disable the old one and `sudo service apache2 restart`.